# Trying to filter and map to output unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Is the code below possible if it is manipulated correctly, it's currently not working for me, i also maybe be going about it the wrong way? Trying to filter and then map so that I can avoid duplicate 'Subnames'

App.js

```
render() {
  const results = !this.state.resultFound
    ? null
    : this.state.search.filter((item, index) =>
        this.state.search.indexOf(item) === index).map(item => (
          <Search
            key={item.key}
            subname={item.subname}
            clickedSub={() => this.getUniqueSubs2(item)}
          />
        ))
      )

  return (
    <div>
      {results}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Search.js

```
const search = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.clickedSub}> {props.subname} </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` method will not work properly since you are not operating over primitive values but on **objects**. The strict comparison `===` will fail in this case.

You could try e.g. `Array#reduce` to get rid of the dupes.

```js
const arr = [{ subname: 'foo', name: 'a' }, { subname: 'boo', name: 'b' }, { subname: 'foo', name: 'c' }];
const r = Object.values(
   arr.reduce((s, a) => (a.subname in s ? a : s[a.subname] = a, s), {}),
);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of "=a, s)" is? got lost there

Comment: @Prav Yeah, sure - `, s)` is just a comma expression - it works the same if you just would write `return s;`

Answer (score 0):

Echo of `indexOf` not working on objects, but an example with filter, indexOf, and map.

```js
let search = [{
  key: 1,
  subname: 'a'
}, {
  key: 2,
  subname: 'a'
}, {
  key: 3,
  subname: 'b'
}, {
  key: 4,
  subname: 'b'
}]
let seen = [];
let result = search.filter((item, index) => {
    if (seen.indexOf(item.subname) === -1) {
      seen.push(item.subname)
      return false
    }
    return true
  })
  .map(o => ({
    newValue: 'abc',
    ...o
  }))
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)
```

```html
<h1 id='test'></h1>
```